# Integrating all the pages with the main menu page

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I want to integrate all the pages into the main page(index.html) Where I have created the left side panel in which all the pages links are given. Now I want to display my other html pages in the grey area. I am able to bring the pages into the main page but Its not fitting into the blank area. Hope I am clear. Thanks in advance for the help.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="scotchApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainController">

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-left">
        <p>
            <br />
            <br />
        </p>
        <b><a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color:white">Administrator</a></b>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#Header">Header Details</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ReportDetails">Report Details</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ProjectIDCreation">Project ID Creation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Display all submission for verify</a></li>
        </ul>

        <b><a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color:white">User</a></b>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Timesheet Information</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

        <ul id="login_signup">
            <li><a href="#" id="login_link">Login <span>&#x25c0;</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="sign_link">SignUp <span>&#x25c0;</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="pull-right">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

index.css

```
.navbar-fixed-left {
  width: 140px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.navbar-fixed-left .navbar-nav > li {
  float: none;  /* Cancel default li float: left */
  width: 139px;
}

.navbar-fixed-left + .container {
  padding-left: 160px;
}

/* On using dropdown menu (To right shift popuped) */
.navbar-fixed-left .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 140px;
}
body{
    position: relative;
    background: url(images/gradient.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:150% 150vh;
}

#login_bar{
width:300px;        
position:fixed;
z-index:10;        
border:1px solid black;   
top:-5px;
right:0px;
}

#header{
width:1000px;    
background-image:url('../images/hf1.jpg'); 
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: relative;
border-radius:5px;
min-height: 100px;
}

#login_signup{
float:right;    
}

#login_signup > li{
float:left;    
list-style: none;
line-height:25px;
padding-top:6px;
display:inline-block;           
}

#login_signup li > a{
font-family:sans-serif;
font-size: 17px;
font-weight: bold;
color:white;
padding:5px;
display:inlineblock;
background-color:black;
border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-o-border-radius:5px;

box-shadow: rgb(0,0,0) 0px 0px 10px;
-moz-box-shadow: rgb(0,0,0) 0px 0px 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: rgb(0,0,0) 0px 0px 10px;
-o-box-shadow:rgb(0,0,0) 0px 0px 10px;
}

#login_signup li span{  
font-size: 12px;        
display:inlineblock;
}

#login_signup li a:hover{
cursor: pointer;
box-shadow: rgb(255,255,255) 0px 0px 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: rgb(255,255,255) 0px 0px 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: rgb(255,255,255) 0px 0px 5px;
-o-box-shadow:rgb(255,255,255) 0px 0px 5px;
border-radius: 2px;
background-color: white;    
color:#006666;
}

#wrapper{
width:1000px;
min-height:600px;    
margin:5px auto;
border-radius:5px;
border-style: solid;
border:solid 1px grey;
box-shadow:rgb(0,0,0) 0px 0px 10px;
-moz-box-shadow: rgb(0,0,0) 0px 0px 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: rgb(0,0,0) 0px 0px 10px;
-o-box-shadow:rgb(0,0,0) 0px 0px 10px;
background-color: black;
}
```

app.js

```
// create the module and name it scotchApp
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
scotchApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/Header', {
            templateUrl: '/Header.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
            controller: 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/contact.html',
            controller: 'contactController'
        });
});
```

Comment: can you post html for any of the other pages and would be really great if you can create a Plnkr for this.

Comment: @Manish as the code will be lengthy i didn't add the other html code. Find the fiddle here [link]["https://jsfiddle.net/a064r7ea/"] . I need the other html page to be displayed in the white blank area.

Comment: @beginner Where is your other HTML that you want to display it in the blank area.

It all depends on your routing URL and the mapping you have provided in JS. If you try to hit URL something like ...../Header then Header.html will be displayed in the div where you have ng-view

Comment: have a look at this https://plnkr.co/edit/uxJGaiv1Rf85joKqnyja?p=preview  you need to provide proper height and width to the body and place you ng-view inside container and provide proper margins

Comment: @Manish Yes you are right. I had to add correct margin. Its working now:)

Comment: @Manish I have another issue now. When I am clicking on header details link its not going to that particular page. It was working initially now I am unable to see the correct output. Can you check my code at [https://plnkr.co/edit/TA71EqoDX8Yu0WyIcgPn?p=preview] .. Please help me with what I am going wrong here.

Comment: it wont work because in `app.config` for the route `#Header` the controller you have given is `mainController` but that does not exist. Change it to `headerCtrl` or create a controller `mainController `

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the correct margin to place the page at the correct position.